# Kali - ext4_find_entry checksumming directory block 0 freezing everything giving input/output error

Tags: kali-linux, ext4, inode

I'm having some problems with Kali Linux installed on a Dell notebook. It is installed on half of my SSD in dual boot with Windows, but I installed Kali later, so GRUB is from the latter. Kali was installed with the "*all files in one partition*" option.

The symptoms are that while I'm working on something, at a certain point I can't do anything anymore:

- If I have a terminal open and type ls, I get `zsh:input-output error`
- If I click on an icon, for example the one in the top left of Kali which opens the menu, it disappears
- Not always, near the wifi icon, the following text appears: `/usr/share/kali-themes/xfce-4-panel-gemon-vpnip.sh: input/output error`

I managed to take a photo of the dmesg output right after the problem happened, i.e.: `__ext4_find_entry:1693: inode #1084174: comm chrome: checksumming directory block 0`

The problem is **very frequent**, it happens every time I access Kali and I am always forced to use `fsck /dev/sda5` when I start it.

The SSD is in good condition, according to SMART. I also installed Crucial Storage Executives in Windows which shows me great statistics and no errors. The firmware is already updated to the latest available: M3CR023.
I have also done several block scans, including from Windows with Disk Genius and there are no bad blocks.

I really have no idea what to check and fix. On Windows everything seems to work without problems.
I am going to run `e2fsck` as suggested, will paste the output

---

It may be unrelated, but I want to expose this behavior too: often the trackpad freezes and the mouse does not respond to commands and the pointer descends diagonally down and left. Everything else works, so much so that I control it with the dualpoint which is located in the center of the keyboard. After a while, the touchpad works again. I mitigate the problem with `sudo xinput disable 11`, but I noticed that the defect also occurs on Windows, so I assume that this behavior has nothing to do with the problem mentioned above.
The interface is:

```
Virtual core pointer                
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

since this is a persistent error on the same files, this sounds like a fundamental filesystem corruption that fsck for some reason can't repair.

So, by far the least work solution here is to copy your personal files off that drive onto a backup medium (you *have* regular backups anyways, don't you, especially in case your SSD is wrong about its own state?), to boot a live linux disk, `blkdiscard` the whole partition, and install a fresh operating system.

Not sure why you *installed* Kali as a dual-boot thing next to Windows – while that's technically possible, Kali was never and is not meant to be used as a day-to-day second boot choice where you'd browse the web in your home wifi etc, [says Kali Linux itself](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/), so this might be a good point to replace your Kali installation with a normal debian.

Do, however, **after** making that backup, force the SSD to do a SMART-selftest of the longer kind. Ext4 really *is* a robust and well-tested file system, and unrepairable errors that "just happened" without the SSD being broken should be much less likely than a consumer-grade SSD not noticing its own demise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

No, I don't know if the error is on the same file. I think I should provide one more instance of the issue, I will when it will present again.  

I don't intend to use Kali for general purposes, but for educational purposes of the use for which it was created. However, I had to install it on SSD because persistent mode on USB doesn't work well for my case.
Thanks!

Comment: if it's different files, then almost certainly you have problems with your SSD! No matter what is the case **make that backup**. Make it **NOW**, before doing anything else.